# Err_connection_refused using meteor uploads

Tags: node.js, file-upload, meteor, upload, image-uploading

I am deploying a meteor application to a digital ocean droplet with meteor upload. Everything goes well, the application gets deployed, database works, seeding of data works etc. But there is one problem i can't seem to be able to solve.

I use the meteor-uploads package (https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) for file uploads. Locally everything goes well, the file gets uploaded, finished callback gets called etc. But once I have deployed the application to the server it keeps giving me on of these errors, :

- POST http://*ip*/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- POST http://*ip*/upload net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
- POST http://*ip*/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Any ideas are welcome, I have searched all over for a solution but none seems to fit my problem. I also installed to a fresh droplet but that didn't help. In none of my browsers (Mac Chrome, safari & firefox) does it work, on my phone (Android 5.0) I get the same errors. I am using the newest Meteor version 1.1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On local host you don't need to set the environmental variables, but the host services provides you should.

Check [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps) to see how to put the environment variables.

Because the file-upload needs a `startup-server-configuration`, like this.

```
//file:/server/init.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
    checkCreateDirectories: true //create the directories for you
  })
});
```

But im not sure if putting this on a startup will work on digital ocean, like i say you you enter it, run `printing` and check if the `/.uploads/` exists

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's not the problem unfortunately. I double-checked it, removed the `/.uploads` folder from my server and deployed again. The `/.uploads` and `/tmp` do get created. I have the same code snippet as you have there. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: after some research seems like you don't have permission to write into that folder maybe did you find something?

Comment: Apparently the permissions where the problem. I thought I checked it before, guess not ;). Thanks for the help!

Comment: So the permissions where the problem but my uploads-folder already did have chmod 755. What the problem was is that the folder was owned by the root user while the user trying to upload was the user made by meteor. So I didn't change the chmod but the owner of the folder with chown. The problem probably occurred because I deployed the uploads-folder to the server and didn't let the package create the folder.